# Eclipse | Permission denied when trying to open sh file under Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse

I develop plug-in that works under Ubuntu. The plug-in is required to install a third party software with which it works. Installation directory is "user home" [System.getProperty("user.home")]

After installation, when I try to open the .sh file via java code from is throwing an exception -

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program >/home/mbaev/Tools/flasher/1.5.0/lua5.1.sh": error=13, Permission denied"

Where should be installed a third party software, after that i can run it without permissions? Why this directory have permissions by default?

Permissions info:

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 mbaev mbaev 605 май  9 11:15 /home/mbaev/Tools/flasher/1.5.0//lua5.1.sh

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `ls -l /home/mbaev/Tools/flasher/1.5.0/lua5.1.sh`.

Comment: But I want to programmatically unarchive the third party software in user home dir and then start the .sh file programmatically without need any permissions, this is possible?

Comment: For a program to run directly, it needs execute rights. `chmod +x /home/mbaev/Tools/flasher/1.5.0//lua5.1.sh` will do that. Alternative you can run it with bash (or any other shell) as `bash /home/mbaev/Tools/flasher/1.5.0//lua5.1.sh`. That should work without execute-rights.

Comment: I resolved this issue with add permission setting when using unarchive tool